# Speed of convergence of Markov chain Monte Carlo

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo

How can I say better for a MCMC in terms of speed? I'm confused with several measures of speed of convergence. I know some people compute the second largest eigenvalue of transition probability matrix. Some compare autocorrelation coefficients. And some others calculate relaxation time.

Is there a well accepted measure so that I can compare different MCMC methods?